# Cannot use fnAddData when table is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, datatables

I'm using a table with the jquery dataTable plugin.
When I use the function `fnAddData` it works, except when the table is empty. Then, I get this error :

> **Cannot read property 'className' of undefined**

This is how I add my data:

```
$("#table-1").dataTable().fnAddData([
            data[0],
            data[1],
            data[2],
            data[3],
            data[4],
            data[5],
            data[6],
            data[7],
            data[8],
            ]);
```

And I have the same problem with fnDeleteRow with this error message:

> **Cannot read property 'nTr' of undefined**

Here's how I use `fnDeleteRow`, I have no trouble when the table is not empty...

```
$("#table-1").dataTable().fnDeleteRow(tr)
```

where tr is a selector.

Am I missing something?

Here's my HTML tab with one last row :

```
<table id="table-1" class="table table-hover table-nomargin table-colored-header        dataTable" aria-describedby="table-1_info">
<thead>
<tr role="row">
<th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Pays</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
<tr class="odd">
<td class=" sorting_1">
<div id="address23name">test</div>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

And here's my JS

```
$("#deleteAddressButton").click(function(){
    var id = $("#deleteAddressId").val();
    $.post("/Contacts/deleteAddress",
            {data: id}, function(data) {
          var id = $.parseJSON(data);
          var tr = $("tr:has(td:has(div:contains(\"address\" + id + \"Name\")))");
          $("#table-1").dataTable().fnDeleteRow(tr)
        });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple jsfiddle, which allows you to add a row to an empty table:
http://jsfiddle.net/7UZGM/

So what's different about your table? When you say "empty", **does it still have a thead/tr/th section and an empty tbody section**? These are required for datatables to work properly.

```
$('#dt').dataTable();

$('#btn').on('click',function() { addData(); });

function addData()
{
    $("#dt").dataTable().fnAddData([
            "col 1", "col 2", "col 3"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the JS, my problem is that when I use .dataTable() on my table, I have an empty <tr></tr> in the tbody, do you know where it could come from ?

Comment: From your code :)   How are you generating the table? Can you show some code for the table generation?  When the page is created, is there an empty TR in the table? Or does this only happen when you delete all rows?  Sorry, but we need more information.

Comment: I looked into my code an I saw where did the problem came from. I had this <tr></tr> because I gave an empty array instead of null to the function tableCells. Ok so now I can add my data with no problems. But I still have one problem when deleting the last element, I get this error message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nTr' of undefined (edit: I'll post some code soon)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't allow DataTables to access the data in the way that it prefers. In order to give it the node that it wants, you will probably need to **apply [0] or .get(0)** to the end of your jQuery object. That is actually what jQuery returns -- an object -- and normally exactly what you would be comfortable working with.

DataTables wants a node.

Here are some links that show the developer giving hints about how to access the data in different circumstances -- but with the same error in the 2nd link:
[here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/107)
and
[here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/15208/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-ntr-of-undefined-fngetposition-with-th-elements/p1)

The moral of the story is that if DataTables is expecting a table "node", you need to do some extra footwork to remove the extra jQuery container that it is placed within.

Your code would, therefore, look like this and I believe should handle your error condition. Otherwise, be sure to search for your error and function name on DataTables.net. That forum is very active and helpful.

```
var tr = $("tr:has(td:has(div:contains(\"address\" + id + \"Name\")))");
$("#table-1").dataTable().fnDeleteRow(tr[0])
```

or

```
var tr = $("tr:has(td:has(div:contains(\"address\" + id + \"Name\")))");
$("#table-1").dataTable().fnDeleteRow(tr.get(0))
```

or of course, add it to the end of your lengthy `$("tr:has...)` statement.

Option 2:

- Just hide the row you want to delete
- If these ideas don't help, you may find [allan's answers here](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/9305/unable-to-get-value-of-the-property-ntr-object-is-null-or-undefined-in-1.9-in-1.8.2-works-fine/p1) insightful.